# How can I improve my grid puzzle solver for complex maps with balls, arrows, and obstacles?

Tags: c, backtracking

I'm working on a grid puzzle where I need to place digits (depicted as balls) in 'H' cells and connect them with arrows. The challenge is to ensure that the balls don't intersect, and the arrows don't land on 'X', though they can 'jump' over them.

I've got a working solution for simpler maps like theses ones:

```
1H
expected ouput: >.
my output: same
```

```
2.X
..H
.H1
expected output:
v..
v..
>.^
my output: same
```

but I'm struggling with more complex ones like this:

```
3..H.2
.2..H.
..H..H
.X.2.X
......
3..H..
expected output:
>>>..v
.>>>.v
>>....
^..v..
^..v..
^.....
my output:
v....v
v>>v.v
v.....
>>vv..
...v..
>>^...
It does not make sense
```

I'm using a backtracking algorithm, and everything seems fine on paper. However, my program isn't solving these trickier maps. Can you help me figure out where I might be going wrong? Maybe suggest some improvements or debugging strategies?

EDIT: I also forgot to mention: 
The number of hits by a ball also indicates the number of squares it traverses the first time it moves. The next hit will go one square less, with each hit decrementing the number of squares the ball traverses by 1. With each new hit, the ball can be hit in a new direction. When the next hit becomes 0 or the ball stops on a hole, the ball can no longer move
EDIT2: It is a coding game puzzle, and here is the [link](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/winamax-sponsored-contest)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void    print(int c, int r, const char map[][r])
{
    for (int y = 0; y < c; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < r; x++)
        {
            if (map[y][x] == '>' || map[y][x] == '<'
                || map[y][x] == '^' || map[y][x] == 'v')
                printf("%c", map[y][x]);
            else
                printf(".");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

bool    constraints(const char c)
{
    return  c == '<' || c == '>' || c == 'F' ||
            c == 'v' || c == '^' || isdigit(c);
}

bool    is_inside(int y, int x, int c, int r)
{
    return  y >= 0 &&
            x >= 0 &&
            y < c &&
            x < r;
}

int    done(bool last_loop, int counter, int y, int x, int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    if (!is_inside(y, x, c, r))
        return -1;
    if (map[y][x] == 'H') {
        map[y][x] = 'F';
        return 1;
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        if (last_loop)
        {
            if (map[y][x] == 'H') {
                map[y][x] = 'F';
                return 1;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool    down(bool last_loop, int counter, int y, int x, int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    int res;
    if ((res = done(last_loop, counter, y, x, c, r, map)) != 0)
        return res == 1;

    if (map[y][x] == 'F')
        return false;
    if (y + 1 < c && !constraints(map[y + 1][x]))
    {
        const char save = map[y][x];
        map[y][x] = 'v';
        if (down(last_loop, counter - 1, y + 1, x, c, r, map))
            return true;
        map[y][x] = save;
    }
    return false;
}

bool    up(bool last_loop, int counter, int y, int x, int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    int res;
    if ((res = done(last_loop, counter, y, x, c, r, map)) != 0)
        return res == 1;

    if (map[y][x] == 'F')
        return false;
    if (y - 1 >= 0 && !constraints(map[y - 1][x]))
    {
        const char save = map[y][x];
        map[y][x] = '^';
        if (up(last_loop, counter - 1, y - 1, x, c, r, map))
            return true;
        map[y][x] = save;
    }
    return false;
}

bool    right(bool last_loop, int counter, int y, int x, int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    int res;
    if ((res = done(last_loop, counter, y, x, c, r, map)) != 0)
        return res == 1;

    if (map[y][x] == 'F')
        return false;
    if (x + 1 < r && !constraints(map[y][x + 1]))
    {
        const char save = map[y][x];
        map[y][x] = '>';
        if (right(last_loop, counter - 1, y, x + 1, c, r, map))
            return true;
        map[y][x] = save;
    }
    return false;
}

bool    left(bool last_loop, int counter, int y, int x, int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    int res;
    if ((res = done(last_loop, counter, y, x, c, r, map)) != 0)
        return res == 1;

    if (map[y][x] == 'F')
        return false;
    if (x - 1 >= 0 && !constraints(map[y][x - 1]))
    {
        const char save = map[y][x];
        map[y][x] = '<';
        if (left(last_loop, counter - 1, y, x - 1, c, r, map))
            return true;
        map[y][x] = save;
    }
    return false;
}

void move_in_grid(int counter, int y, int x, int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    for (int i = counter; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (y + i < c)
        {
            if (down(i == 1, i, y, x, c, r, map)) {
                y += i;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (y - i >= 0)
        {
            if (up(i == 1, i, y, x, c, r, map)) {
                y -= i;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (x + i < r)
        {
            if (right(i == 1, i, y, x, c, r, map)) {
                x += i;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (x - i >= 0)
        {
            if (left(i == 1, i, y, x, c, r, map)) {
                x -= i;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

void start_from_digit(int c, int r, char map[][r])
{
    for (int y = 0; y < c; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < r; x++)
        {
            if (isdigit(map[y][x]))
                move_in_grid(map[y][x] - '0', y, x, c, r, map);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    int columns, rows;
    printf ("For 6x5 grid, enter 65 and so on\n");
    scanf ("%d%d", &rows, &columns);
    char map [columns] [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
        scanf("%s", map[i]);
    }
    start_from_digit (columns, rows, map);
    print (columns, rows, map);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hello!  I think it will help a *lot* if you share 1.)  *one* "tricky" map that isn't working, 2.) expected output 3.) actual output.   Good job on what you have shared so far, great start.

Comment: Is this problem similar to [Flow Free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_Free)? (with the minor difference that you don't have to fill the entire grid, but each line has to have a specific length)

Comment: Thank you for the advice grep spears and @lax48 After reading the article, I can say it closely aligns with what I need to do

Comment: The first suggestion I have is to make sure you are not mixing the meanings of `x`, `y`, `columns`, `rows`, `left`, etc. For example, at the beginning you ask the shape of the grid in "rows x columns" format, but then you get #`columns` strings (instead of #`rows`). And seeing the code, their meaning seem to be a bit mixed. Making your variable and function names clearer and consistent can help you find some bugs!

Comment: Also, giving `foo` a more descriptive name would be helpful (and if you can't find any, that's a good hint that you may want to refactor your code/logic)

Comment: I have a few questions. What does the digit mean? I thought it was the total number of steps you have to do to hit the goal. But in your second example, `2` does three steps (2 down, 1 right). What am I missing? Looking at your code the `2` seems to mean "you can have a max of 2 steps per direction". Does the order of down, up, left, right checks matter? (so, is there any privileged direction? Or should your logic behave in any order?)

Comment: Certainly! In this exercise, the digit associated with a ball represents the total number of moves it can make. The first move uses the maximum number of squares, and each subsequent move decreases the number of squares by 1.
For example, if a ball has a value of 2, it means it can initially move 2 squares, then 1 square on the next move.
In summary, the digit associated with a ball indicates the total moves it can make, with each subsequent move covering one less square. The order of checks for movements depends on your program logic, but it should remain consistent for accurate results

Comment: Regarding the order of checks (down, up, left, right), the order can be important, yes but for now I'm not sure, I think the preferred direction depends on how I choose to handle ball movements. PS: I am refactoring the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256387/discussion-between-lax48-and-tristan-debas).